# awk command to extract columns from a csv file whose header contains a certain substring

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a huge csv file that is of the format

```
aaa1, "aaa2, aa214", aa21, "aa, a14", aa211, aa44, aaa445 
data, data, data, data, data, data, data,
........................................
........................................
```

I want to extract columns whose header contains a specific string, let's say `a2`. For the example above, this includes columns `aaa2` and `aa21` and many more.

The awk command I tried was

```
awk --csv 'NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /a2/) print $i}' file.csv
```

But this only returns the matched headers, not the columns under them.
Please point me in the right direction. I am using a Linux system.

Comment: I tried the page in the link, the command did not work, perl did not produce any output, awk command gave garbage output

Comment: By providing 1 line of sample data that just says `data, data, data, data, data, data, data,` we can't tell when testing a potential solution if it's outputting the correct fields or not since thy all have the same value. It's important when providing an example that it contain truly representative sample data that can be used when testing to give a clear, simple pass/fail result. And never add `...`s - they just clutter up the example and make it untestable.

Comment: Do your rows with `data` fields actually end in comma? That can signify an empty field at the end of the line (and may be a source of error). Thx.

Answer (score 6):

`mlr` does support this kind of bogus CSV format and can cut fields based on regexps:

```
$ mlr --csv --csv-trim-leading-space --allow-ragged-csv-input cut -rf a2 your-file.csv
"aaa2, aa214",aa21,aa211
data,data,data
```

That won't scale to CSVs that don't fit in memory though. With `--allow-ragged-csv-input` to cope with CSVs that don't have the same number of fields in each row like in your sample, it has to read the file fully in any case to know how man columns there are (the ones without headers get assigned numerical headers automatically).

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk for `FPAT` and assuming fields don't contain newline characters:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|\\s*("([^"]|"")*")\\s*' -v OFS=',' '
    NR==1 {
        for ( inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++ ) {
            if ( $inFldNr ~ /a2/ ) {
                out2in[++numOutFlds] = inFldNr
            }
        }
    }
    {
        for ( outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++ ) {
            inFldNr = out2in[outFldNr]
            printf "%s%s", $inFldNr, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' file.csv
 "aaa2, aa214", aa21, aa211
 data, data, data
```

I'm not using `--csv` (also requires GNU awk) because your input file is not valid CSV (has blanks between `,`s and first `"`s, and has more data columns than headers because of the trailing `,` at the end of the second line) and so a CSV parser shouldn't be expected to be able to handle it. Also, even if you solved that problem, `--csv` will strip the quotes from around each column header and I'm guessing you want to retain them which is slightly problematic when not all fields are enclosed in double quotes. Using `--csv` is only noticeably better than using a correct `FPAT` setting when fields can contain newlines and you want to strip quotes from around fields anyway.

If you did want to try `--csv` then this (untested) MIGHT work for you:

```
awk --csv -v OFS=',' '
    NR==1 {
        for ( inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++ ) {
            if ( $inFldNr ~ /a2/ ) {
                out2in[++numOutFlds] = inFldNr
            }
        }
    }
    {
        for ( outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++ ) {
            inFldNr = out2in[outFldNr]
            outVal = $inFldNr
            if ( outVal ~ ("[" OFS ORS "\"]") ) {
                gsub(/"/,"\"\"",outVal)
                outVal = "\"" outVal "\""
            }
            printf "%s%s", outVal, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' file.csv
```

but there's no easy way to tell when adding `"`s in the loop which leading/trailing spaces, if any, were originally inside vs outside of quotes so I'm just wrapping the whole field in quotes.

See [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more on parsing CSV with awk.

Comment: Regarding gawk removing quotes with `--csv` - yeah, I had asked the gawk providers and Kernighan to not do that, or at least give us an option we could use to disable that, as it makes dealing with "irregular" CSVs where you just want to reproduce the input fields as-is in the output, harder than it should be but I couldn't persuade them. Oh well.

Comment: That `awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|\\s*("([^"]|"")*")\\s*' -v OFS=','` doesn't seem to work properly when the first field is empty and not quoted (as in the output of `echo ,foo`) with gawk 5.0.1 at least (like on Ubuntu 20.04). OK in 5.1.0 (Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, that was a bug in gawk 5.0.1, see the bug report at https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-10/msg00041.html which includes a workaround (assigning FPAT to itself after the record was read and before using the fields).

Comment: Thanks. Actually as noted there, since your code is accessing `NF` it does actually work around it and is not affected.

Comment: Ah, sorry, no, it is affected if the first field is among those to be output as NF is not accessed for NR != 1. Adding just a `NF;` at the standard of the action would work around it

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*...with Raku's `Text::CSV` module:*

```
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'csv(in => csv(in => $*IN, sep => ", "), out => $*OUT);'  <  file
```

*Above will read the CSV file (all columns) into memory. The file is taken in via `$*IN` std-in and all columns are output via `$*OUT` std-out. Note the custom `", "` field separator.*

*To filter-in specific columns (dropping all others), use Raku's `grep` with the `:k` key parameter, which returns a numeric index of any found columns:*

```
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my  @aoa = csv(in => $*IN, sep => ", ");
                        my  @col-nbrs = @aoa[0].grep(/a2/, :k);
                        for @aoa.map( *.[@col-nbrs]) {
                            .map(q["] ~ * ~ q["]).join("\t").put
                        };'  <  file
```

Sample Input:

```
aaa1_a, "aaa2, aa214_b", aa21_c, "aa, a14_d", aa211_e, aa44_f, aaa445_g
data1_a, data1_b, data1_c, data1_d, data1_e, data1_f, data1_g,
data2_a, data2_b, data2_c, data2_d, data2_e, data2_f, data2_g,
```

Sample Output (TSV, from above):

```
"aaa2, aa214_b" "aa21_c"    "aa211_e"
"data1_b"   "data1_c"   "data1_e"
"data2_b"   "data2_c"   "data2_e"
```

*Above contains all column-names matching "a2". To make the output more readable each field's text has been enclosed in quotation marks, and then `join`ed on `\t` tabs. Without adding quotation marks, the code simplifies quite a bit. Below columns are joined on `\t\t` and output:*

```
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my  @aoa = csv(in => $*IN, sep => ", ");
                        my  @col-nbrs = @aoa[0].grep(/a2/, :k);
                        for @aoa.map( *.[@col-nbrs]) {
                            $_.join("\t\t").put
                        };'  <  file
aaa2, aa214_b       aa21_c      aa211_e
data1_b     data1_c     data1_e
data2_b     data2_c     data2_e
```

*Finally, you can take advantage of `Text::CSV`'s output capabilities, which will--by default:  1. `join` columns on `,` comma, and  2. double-quote fields containing whitespace.*

```
% raku -MText::CSV -e 'my  @aoa = csv(in => $*IN, sep => ", ");
                       my  @col-nbrs = @aoa[0].grep(/a2/, :k);
                       my  @filtered; for @aoa.map( *.[@col-nbrs] ) {
                           @filtered.push($_); 
                       };  csv(in => @filtered, out => $*OUT);'  <  file
"aaa2, aa214_b",aa21_c,aa211_e
data1_b,data1_c,data1_e
data2_b,data2_c,data2_e
```

https://raku.land/zef:Tux/Text::CSV
https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.md
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

Another very convenient tool is [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/installation/index?version=latest&environment=cli&installer=binary&platform=win). Running

```
duckdb --csv -c "SELECT COLUMNS('.*a2.*') from read_csv_auto('input.csv',HEADER = true)" >output.csv
```

you get

| aaa2,aa214 | aa21 | aa211 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data |
| data | data | data |